# Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. even though I'm using the ?. (optional)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've constructed types for my React compoenent props

```
export type EventObj {
  id: string
  observations?: string[]
  note?: string
}
```

I use these in my React component like this:

```
<GameCard 
  id={game.id}
  observations={game.observations} //gets highlighted by TS
  note={game.note} //gets highlighted by TS
/>
```

Which is defined like this as a component:

```
const GameCard: React.FC<EventObj> = ({
  id
  observations
  note
}) => {
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>{note}</h1>
    {observations.map(item => <h1>{item}</h1>)}
   </div>
  )
}
```

The error I'm getting for the highlights at `observations` and `notes` is:

```
Type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
App.tsx(16, 3): The expected type comes from property 'observations' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & EventObj & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

I've even tried doing `observations?: string[] | undefined` but that doesn't solve it

Comment: What's a `game`?

Comment: If `observations` could potentially be undefined, you can't just `map` over it assuming it'll be an array. This is what the compiler is warning you about. Instead, you need to either guard against undefined prior to trying to `map`, or guard against `undefined` prior to rendering the entire component (depending on your use case).

Comment: Can you put a working example in a typescript [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6qvN)?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  (For example, your `type` definition has a syntax error; this is not the only problem) This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `observations` could potentially be undefined, you can't just `map` over it assuming it'll be an array. This is what the compiler is warning you about. Instead, you need to either guard against undefined prior to trying to `map`, or guard against `undefined` prior to rendering the entire component (depending on your use case).

In the following example, we make sure `observations` and `note` exist before rendering the `GameCard`:

```
{game.note && game.observations && <GameCard 
  id={game.id}
  observations={game.observations}
  note={game.note}
/>}
```

Comment: very helpful! how could I guard against undefined prior to trying to map?

Comment: You could do `observations?.map(item => <h1>{item}</h1>)` or `observations && observations.map(item => <h1>{item}</h1>)`